# How can I reduce this formula as the Excel said "You've entered too many arguments for this function."?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

`=IF(ISBLANK($G6),"", IF($L6="Length",(INDEX('PRODUCT SPEC'!I$3:I$253,MATCH($H6&$G6,'PRODUCT SPEC'!$A$3:$A$253&'PRODUCT SPEC'!$D$3:$D$253,0))), IF($L6="Cuff",(INDEX('PRODUCT SPEC'!K$3:K$253,MATCH($H6&$G6,'PRODUCT SPEC'!$A$3:$A$253&'PRODUCT SPEC'!$D$3:$D$253,0)))), IF($L6="Palm",(INDEX('PRODUCT SPEC'!M$3:M$253,MATCH($H6&$G6,'PRODUCT SPEC'!$A$3:$A$253&'PRODUCT SPEC'!$D$3:$D$253,0)))), IF($L6="Finger",(INDEX('PRODUCT SPEC'!O$3:O$253,MATCH($H6&$G6,'PRODUCT SPEC'!$A$3:$A$253&'PRODUCT SPEC'!$D$3:$D$253,0))))))`

Answer (score 2):

Not a fan of concatenated values in a lookup, but at least the following can give you an idea on how to drastically decrease length:

```
=IF(ISBLANK($G6),"",INDEX('PRODUCT SPEC'!I$3:O$253,MATCH($H6&$G6,'PRODUCT SPEC'!$A$3:$A$253&'PRODUCT SPEC'!$D$3:$D$253,0),(MATCH($L6,{"Length","Cuff","Palm","Finger"},0)*2)-1))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it does solve my problem. I am a new learner of the excel formulation, may I know what are the *2 and -1 function in this formulation?

Comment: The `*2` and `-1` are there to create a number in the array `{1,3,5,7}`. We need this to pick the right column in the `INDEX('PRODUCT SPEC'!I$3:O$253`.

Answer (score 0):

In case of such long formulas it's always a good idea to copy it in a text editor and format so you can better track what happens.

Your formatted formula:

```
=IF(
    ISBLANK($G6)
    ,""
    , IF(
        $L6="Length"
        ,(
            INDEX(
                'PRODUCT SPEC'!I$3:I$253
                ,MATCH(
                    $H6&$G6
                    ,'PRODUCT SPEC'!$A$3:$A$253&'PRODUCT SPEC'!$D$3:$D$253
                    ,0
                )
            )
        )
        , IF(
            $L6="Cuff"
            ,(
                INDEX(
                    'PRODUCT SPEC'!K$3:K$253
                    ,MATCH(
                        $H6&$G6
                        ,'PRODUCT SPEC'!$A$3:$A$253&'PRODUCT SPEC'!$D$3:$D$253
                        ,0
                    )
                )
            )
            )
        , IF(
            $L6="Palm"
            ,(
                INDEX(
                    'PRODUCT SPEC'!M$3:M$253
                    ,MATCH(
                        $H6&$G6
                        ,'PRODUCT SPEC'!$A$3:$A$253&'PRODUCT SPEC'!$D$3:$D$253
                        ,0
                    )
                )
            )
            )
        , IF(
            $L6="Finger"
            ,(
                INDEX(
                    'PRODUCT SPEC'!O$3:O$253
                    ,MATCH(
                        $H6&$G6
                        ,'PRODUCT SPEC'!$A$3:$A$253&'PRODUCT SPEC'!$D$3:$D$253
                        ,0
                    )
                )
            )
            )
        )
    )
```

As you see your second `IF` has too many parameters, probably something went wrong with nesting. I can't tell you how exactly it should look like as don't now the logic behind, but on the formatted version it should be pretty easy to fix